# Difference between onKey(), OnKeyDown() and dispatchKeyEvent() methods provided by Android?

Tags: android, events, key

What is the difference between onKey(), OnKeyDown() and dispatchKeyEvent() methods provided by Android?
I Would like to know when and where each of these can be used.
Please shed some light into this.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Tracing the source code of the [5.1 Source for the View Class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java/). It would seem that [`dispatchKeyEvent()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java/#View.dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) is the first method called by the system. Overloading it will prevent any and all key events from being called unless the base version is called.

`dispatchKeyEvent()`'s first move is to attempt to pass the event to an [`onKeyListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) if there is one. This is when `onKey()` is called. If the `onKey()` implementation returns `true`, `dispatchKeyEvent()` will return there and other events will not be called.

If there is no `onKeyListener` or the `onKeyListener`'s `onKey()` method returned `false`, `dispatchKeyEvent()` will then call the `KeyEvent`'s [`dispatch()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/KeyEvent.java#KeyEvent.dispatch%28android.view.KeyEvent.Callback%2Candroid.view.KeyEvent.DispatcherState%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) method. Which will then in turn call all the methods in the [`KeyEvent.Callback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html) interface on your view. This includes [`onKeyDown()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) and [`onKeyUp()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyUp%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29).

Comment: cannot be said any better!

Comment: So, instead of using both `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp`, I could also just use `dispatchKeyEvent`? Does this have any drawbacks? I had to do this, because `onKeyDown` wouldn't be triggered for most of the keys, for some reason. When I changed to `dispatchKeyEvent`, it worked.

Comment: @keinabel Overloading `dispatchKeyEvent` is an option. But unless you call the base version no other related events will be fired. In your situation my guess would be that your events are being consumed by an `onKeyListener` before `KeyEvent.dispatch()` is called, or that the key presses are being seen as an `onKeyMultiple` event by the `dispatch()` method.

Answer (score 2):

**DispatchKeyEvent**
Hardware key events are always delivered to the View currently in focus. They are dispatched starting from the top of the View hierarchy, and then down, until they reach the appropriate destination. If your View (or a child of your View) currently has focus, then you can see the event travel through the dispatchKeyEvent() method. In short, dispatchKeyEvent() will be only called if TextView/EditText is in focus.

**onKeyDown** Called when a key was pressed down and not handled by any of the views inside of the activity