# How to dispatchKeyEvent to currentView in TabHost

Tags: android

I need to change the KeyEvent dispatch in TabActivity. If the current tab content activity/view can handled the KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Back,  let it handled it. If not, show dialog to tip like this:"Would you want exit?". How can do this?

I have tried by this code in my TabActivity:(can't implement my demand)

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(Event event){
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        if(!mTabHost.getCurrentView.dispatchKeyEvent(event)){
            showDialog(0);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230251/1294681) can make you clear.

you should override **onKeyDown** method, and directly call **mTabHost.onKeyDown(...)** method, check it return result, if false, it means you should show the exit message to user.
hope can help you.