# biased dispatchKeyEvent?

Tags: android

I have this code that listens for ENTER and MULTIPLY and calls a method when they get pressed.The problem is that it only calls it when enter is pressed,it doesn't work for multiply ? What am i doing wrong ?

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            enter();

            return true;
        }




    }
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_MULTIPLY) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            enter();

            return true;
        }




    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
};
```

EDIT : Tried with `KEYCODE_STAR` still doesn't work..is it bugged ?

Answer (score 0):

use below `onKeyDown(..)` overriden method instead. i.e

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        enter();
        return true;
    }

    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_MULTIPLY) {
        enter();
        return true;               
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Check out [this SO Q&A thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230251/321272) for further explanation

Comment: Have you deleted/commented out dispatchKeyEvent(..) ? If not please do so and then test.