# Are the Activity's dispatch*() methods the initial entry point handling their respective events/data?

Tags: android

I am working on an Activity that I want to gather all of the input for the application (and I really do mean all of it) and pass it to my handling system. While this seems straight forward I have found the documentation lacking in this area as to call order of the methods of the Activity to see where to best handle this. From [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7846050/498522) it is explained that the call order is dispatchKeyEvent() then onKeyUp() or onKeyDown() depending on the details of the event.

What I would like to know is if this holds true for the rest of the dispatch*() methods associated with the Activity object. I have been through the documentation quite a few times and I am hoping that I am just not searching for the right set of keywords. That previous question however, having gone to sorting through the source code, makes me feel it may not be in there.

The specific methods I am interested in are dispatchGenericMotionEvent(), dispatchKeyEvent(), dispatchTouchEvent() and dispatchTrackballEvent(). I would be interested in knowing if this is just a design paradigm in general though... dispatch*() before on*(). Is anyone able to confirm this is the call flow for events of an Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do event interception in the dispatchKey or dispatchTouch method.

Generally speaking, the sequence is as below

1. Call Activity.dispatchXX, if you return true, that is to tell the framework the event is consumed by this method, thus, no one from behind could get this event. If you just peek it and return super.dispatchXX, the event will be passed on.
2. Call View.onXXListener, this is the specified handler of view, if you return true here, it will also end by here. If you return false, it will be passed on.
3. Call Activity.onXX method, this is final method called if 1 and 2 haven't consume the event.