# DispatchKeyEvent Android

Tags: java, android

I would capture the keycode of the keyboard when an user tape a text in my application, this code it works fine with the android emulator but in real device the toast doesn't work :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnKeyListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Key dispatch : "+   String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Key onKey :" + String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put a log info in function to make sure it's invoked when debugging in the real device.

Comment: In the real device when I tape a text  the dispatchKeyEvent function isn't invoked why ?

Comment: Did function onKey get called?

Comment: This link might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846050/difference-between-onkey-onkeydown-and-dispatchkeyevent-methods-provided/12230251#12230251

Comment: No, with the stock virtual keyboard any function is called why ? With the android emulator my code works fine with my physical keyboard..