# overloaded dispatchKeyEvent method freezes app when adding some post-processing code inside it

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner, keyevent

I'm currently working on an app that uses a barcode scanner for scanning some bar codes. So, I'm capturing the data by overloading the *dispatchKeyEvent* method. Everything works fine, as long as I'm not trying to post-process the prompted bar code.

For example, this code snippet works as expected.

```java
private var promptedEAN:String = ""
override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if(event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            val pressedKey: Char = event.getUnicodeChar().toChar()
            promptedEAN += pressedKey

            val eTMengeKomm = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eTMengeKomm)
            eTMengeKomm.setText(promptedEAN, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)

            val etCharge = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eTCharge)
            etCharge.setText(promptedEAN, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)

            val etMHD = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eTMHD)
            etMHD.setText(promptedEAN, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
       }

       return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
}
```

**BUT**, as soon as I want to post-process the prompted barcode inside the *dispatchKeyEvent* method, the whole app **freezes**. In this case, I have to go to to Settings -> App -> Force Stop to kill my app, because none of the buttons work either.

My post-processing code works without any problems - I tried it out in with a test string in the *onCreate* method of my activity.

My question is **why** I'm getting this behavior with the *dispatchKeyEvent* method?

This is my code. I'm filling the HashMap with the key-value pairs in the *OnCreate* method, which is starting before firing the *dispatchKeyEvent*.

```java
    private var promptedEAN:String = ""
    private var testPromptedEAN:String = "" //"C10207613037926927200015200600370098$1092547017L4"
    private val hashMap : HashMap<String, Int> = HashMap()

    override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if(event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            val pressedKey: Char = event.getUnicodeChar().toChar()
            promptedEAN += pressedKey
            testPromptedEAN = promptedEAN


            val eTMengeKomm = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eTMengeKomm)
            eTMengeKomm.setText(promptedEAN, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)

            val etCharge = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eTCharge)
            etCharge.setText(promptedEAN, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)

            val etMHD = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eTMHD)
            etMHD.setText(promptedEAN, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)

            if (testPromptedEAN.contains("C1",true) or testPromptedEAN.contains("C0",true)) { // EAN-128 Code
                var pos:Int = 2 // init pos
                var tail:String = testPromptedEAN.substring(pos) // init tail
                var lookInString:String =""

                    while (pos<testPromptedEAN.length-1) {
                        var searchString:String = testPromptedEAN.substring(pos, pos+2) // look into 2-digit codes first
                        if (hashMap.containsKey(searchString)){
                        var lengthData4code:Int = hashMap.getValue(searchString) // get length of data for code from hash table
                        if (tail.length<lengthData4code){
                            lengthData4code = tail.length
                            lookInString = tail.substring(searchString.length, lengthData4code)

                        } else {
                            lookInString = tail.substring(searchString.length, searchString.length+lengthData4code) // data (part)string
                        }

                        if (lookInString.indexOf("$")>=0) { // string size is actually shorter than expected
                        lookInString = tail.substring(searchString.length,searchString.length+lookInString.indexOf("$"))
                        pos += (searchString.length + lookInString.length + 1)
                        } else {
                        pos += (searchString.length+ lengthData4code)
                        }

                        if (pos>=testPromptedEAN.length-1) {tail = ""}
                        else {tail = testPromptedEAN.substring(pos)}


                        if (searchString.contains("37", false)) {
                        //val eTMengeKomm = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eTMengeKomm)
                        eTMengeKomm.setText(lookInString, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                        }

                        if (searchString.contains("10", false)) {
                        //val etCharge = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eTCharge)
                        etCharge.setText(lookInString, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                        }

                        if (searchString.contains("15", false)) {
                        //val etMHD = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eTMHD)
                        etMHD.setText(lookInString, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably, the loop never exists for some reason. Did you step through the code with a debugger yet? If not, I highly recommend it.

Comment: Why do this in dispatchKeyEvent? It seems to me that you only want to process a barcode once, not on each letter as it is entered.

Comment: @Enselic the loop exists and I was using the debugger to test the code. As I mentioned in my post, the code works properly, if it runs outside the dispatchkeyevent method. 

You can test the code if you use `private var testPromptedEAN:String = "C10207613037926927200015200600370098$1092547017L4`, only the hash key-values types need to be added separately

Comment: @dharms this was the only event that worked good with my barcode scanner, on the other side, I wasn't able to find any other method that will process the barcode at once, which means that this method is called multiple times until the `ENTER` code comes at the end. This could be even the possible answer to my question, why the post-processing code freezes the app. Thank you so much.

Comment: You could use dispatchKeyEvent to just listen for `ENTER` in that case, and then read the contents from the EditText I'm assuming this value is populating.

Comment: @dharms the problem exists even if I use the _onKeyDown_ method instead of the _dispacthKeyEvent_ method. I get the same bahaviour. There is no method in Android that can capture the whole barcode at once - the barcode can be captured with the _getUnicodeChar_ method character-wise only. Or maybe I'm missing an _onKeyListener_ like explained in this post [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846050/difference-between-onkey-onkeydown-and-dispatchkeyevent-methods-provided) I've tried to read the values from EditText as well, this was not possible because the app has frozen again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I **solved** this problem:

First of all, I got rid of the overloaded `dispachKeyEvent` method. This was making a lot of mess in my app, in my case, the back and the middle button were not reacting at all. A barcode USB scanner should be mostly recognized from Android as a external keyboard, so this method was not needed for capturing barcodes into specific `EditText` field(s). After that, I've set the focus on the first `EditText` field and prompted the barcode there.

Secondly, I've learned that a `while`loop **doesn't work** in an active UI thread - this was the reason, why my app was freezing all the time. That's why I've implemented an `AsyncTask` as inner class in my Activity and placed all the backround processing logic into the overloaded `doInBackround` method from the `AsyncTask`. In the `onPostExecute` method, I've set all the needed values for my `EditText` fields.

UPDATE: I've lifted the whole background logic into a `ViewModel` and finally got rid of the `AsyncTask`.