# onKeyUp doesn't handle Enter from hard keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard-events

I have an activity with a set of buttons on it, it resembles a NumPad keyboard.

**My purpose:** to do some terminal for input data with help of little (hard) “usb NumPad keyboard” – so interface looks as NumPad – just a set of Buttons.

I want to handle all the keyboard events to do with them what I need to do (my own function for each button). Overrided functions `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` – and they do all that I need, except handling the ***Enter*** key. In these two functions it’s not an event at all as I see.
On Enter activity opens menu, so Enter is some special function – not for me, but for system.

All the topics here that I saw (how to handle “Enter”) are about soft keyboard or EditView. I don’t have on my activity any editable, I just want to catch Enter event, or maybe possible link Enter with some of the Buttons on activity.

```
    override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    Toast.makeText(this,keyCode.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    val res: Int = when (keyCode) {
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_0 -> 0
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 -> 0

        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_1 -> 1
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1 -> 1
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN_LEFT -> 1

        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_DOT -> 10

        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUM_LOCK -> 11

        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER -> 16 //never happens

        else -> -1
    }
    if (res>=0) doAction(res)

    return if (res == -1) super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
    else true
}
```

Comment: yes. but onKeyUp doesn't handle it. It can handle even NumLock but not Enter.

Comment: added to post onKeyUp

Comment: what if you use [KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_ENTER)?

Comment: I can do it, but it's not a problem. Problem is  - on Enter  - onKeyUp doesn't even called on debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dispatchKeyEvent` to handle enter:

```
override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event:KeyEvent):Boolean {
   if (event.getAction() === KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
   {
      Toast.makeText(this,event.getKeyCode().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      return true
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks. thats it. dispatchKeyEvent - handles ALL keyb-events and do it first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846050/difference-between-onkey-onkeydown-and-dispatchkeyevent-methods-provided