# Keypress on xamarin form not entry

Tags: android, xamarin, keypress

I have a Xamarin Android form (content page) and I want when the user presses the a certain keyboard key to take a certain action, like calling a method. I can not find anywhere any solution to that. 
If there is anyone knowing how to do this I would really appreciate his/her help.

Thank you

Comment: F1, F2 and F3 on Android Keyboard? I think you have confused few thngs here. Android keyboard doesnt have those butttons.

Comment: We are using some barcode scanners (terminals) that run on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding `DispatchKeyEvent` in your `MainActivity`

```
    public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {
        // if the Keycode is A .. there's lots of these
        //you'll have to checkout the Keycode class for more options
        //this example will fire the following code when 'A' is pressed
        if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.A)
        {
            //invoke your method here
        } 

        //return base if needed, otherwise keystrokes won't get automatically passed into textboxes etc and stuff will act wacky
        return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activity.dispatchkeyevent?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

if this doesn't work you can also override `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` and `OnKey` AFAIK

[Difference between onKey(), OnKeyDown() and dispatchKeyEvent() methods provided by Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846050/difference-between-onkey-onkeydown-and-dispatchkeyevent-methods-provided)